# Cannot draw geometery on WorldWind

Tags: postgis, geojson, worldwind

I'm trying to draw my geometery on worldwind but it keeps saying

> WARNING: Unspecified coordinate system

and draws a default blue line in the middle of nowhere.

The procedure is that I populate my db with a geometery like this:

```
INSERT INTO newroutesegments (name, geom) VALUES ('RouteSegment1', ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('{ "type": "MultiLineString", "coordinates": [ [ [100.0, 0.0], [101.0, 1.0] ], [ [102.0, 2.0], [103.0, 3.0] ] ], "crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}} }'));
```

At this point I checked my db and the geom is there and the SRID is 4326 which is good! However when I query this and want to draw it on world wind it gives me the same error. This is my geometery in case you want to see it:

```
0105000020E610000002000000010200000002000000000000000000594000000000000000000000000000405940000000000000F03F010200000002000000000000000080594000000000000000400000000000C059400000000000000840
```

Comment: You do not mention any product from the ArcGIS platform in your question so I removed the arcgis-10.0 tag from it.

Comment: How do you fetch the geometry from db? You need a LatLon or a sequese of LatLons to draw a shape. How do you prepare the latlons?